# How can I retrieve data synchronously from Apache Cassandra using Phantom-dsl in Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am using Scala_2.11.7, Apache Cassasndra_3.9 and Phantom-dsl_2.6.1.
When I retrieve data from Cassandra using phantom, phantom always returns data in Future. But I want the result synchronously. Is there any way to retrieve data from cassandra synchronously using phantom?

Comment: Why not to add method that will wrap the call to Phantom with next `.get` on the Future?

Comment: @AlexOtt I don't get what you are talking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @jonyroy You should have an extremely strong use case for doing thing synchronously, or otherwise you're embracing a performance bottleneck and an anti-pattern willingly. Phantom goes to great lengths to keep all execution async, and you should take advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your execution to be synchronous you must block the calling thread and wait to the future to complete. This is (as scala lang doc says) "strongly discouraged" because performance is severely impaired.

If you have a function that returns a Future[T], you can use Await.result, for example:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val fresult : Future[Int] = getRecord()

val result: Int = Await.result(fresult, 5 seconds)
```